# Repeated Measures with a covariate

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I have two continuous variables; a pretest and a post test. They seem to have significance in paired samples; p=.000. However I wonder what caused the post test to be better than the pre test and I suspect that another continuous variable predicted the increase in post test. Here is my research design:
Learners took a pretest on 15 vocabulary. Then they read a paragraph which included these words. While they read, I recorded their eye movements and fixation duration. Then they have taken a post test. Post test results are better. And I observed that learners paid more attention to unknown words then they did for known words while reading. So after reading and paying attention to unknown words, they became familiar with the words and did better in post test. "Fixation on unknown words" is my predictor which predicts the significance between pre and post test. All of them are continuous. But which test should I use? Generalized linear model, multivariate, repeated measures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be modeled a number of ways, but since you have a very basic pre/post test design, consider modeling with a simple linear regression, with pre-test score as a covariate and "Fixation" as the independent variable of interest. Something like this:

$Words=\hat{\alpha}+\hat{\beta_1} Fixation + \hat{\beta_2} pretest+\epsilon$

This will control for the baseline pre-test score, and allow you to see the independent effect of Fixation. You may also test hypotheses about whether Fixation has a different relationship with Words based on pre-test score. You could either treat pretest as a continuous or categorical variable, depending on what you are interested in and the interpretability of the result.